# Why Botium CLI fails extracting utterances data from DialogFlow agent?

Tags: dialogflow-es, botium-box

After setting up Botium and connecting it to my DialogFlow agent (with a DialogFlow Admin Service Account on Google Cloud Platform), I tried to extract the data (intents and utterances) from DialogFlow automatically with the command `botium-cli nlpextract`. This is the error I got:

```
user@ubuntu20:~/workspace$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/google_key.json"
user@ubuntu20:~/workspace$ botium-cli nlpextract --config botium.json --convos dataset_botium --verbose
  botium-cli Using Botium configuration file botium.json +0ms
  botium-cli-nlp command options: { _: [ 'nlpextract' ],
  botium-cli-nlp   config: 'botium.json',
  botium-cli-nlp   c: 'botium.json',
  botium-cli-nlp   convos: [ 'dataset_botium' ],
  botium-cli-nlp   C: [ 'dataset_botium' ],
  botium-cli-nlp   verbose: true,
  botium-cli-nlp   v: true,
  botium-cli-nlp   '$0': '/usr/local/bin/botium-cli' } +0ms

 (...)

  botium-connector-PluginConnectorContainer-helper Botium plugin loaded from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-connector-dialogflow/index.js +0ms
  botium-connector-dialogflow Validate called +0ms
  botium-connector-BaseContainer _RunCustomHook onBuild finished +0ms
  botium-connector-dialogflow Build called +1ms
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp Dialogflow agent: {
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp   "parent": ####,
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp   "displayName": ####,
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp   "defaultLanguageCode": "it",
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp   "timeZone": "Europe/Kaliningrad",
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp   "enableLogging": true,
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp   "matchMode": "MATCH_MODE_HYBRID",
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp   "classificationThreshold": 0.30000001192092896,
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp   "apiVersion": "API_VERSION_V2",
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp   "tier": "TIER_STANDARD"
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp } +0ms
  botium-connector-dialogflow-nlp Utterances files not found for Default Fallback Intent, checking for utterances in intents/Default Fallback Intent_usersays_en-us.json and intents/Default Fallback Intent_usersays_it.json. Ignoring intent. +20ms
  botium-connector-dialogflow Clean called +2s
  botium-connector-BaseContainer _RunCustomHook onClean finished +2s
  botium-connector-BaseContainer Cleanup rimrafing temp dir /home/user/workspace/botiumwork/agent-name 20200722 124913 wTImF +0ms
Failed to extract utterances: Cannot read property 'intents' of undefined
```

I can't find anything online about this. If I download the agent in a zip file, all the 21 intents which I inserted are available, each one with 85 training utterances.

(I am using Ubuntu20 on an Entroware Apollo laptop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the [Botium Dialogflow Connector](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-dialogflow). It is fixed now and will be included in the next release.

In the meantime, you can replace the latest release of the connector with the latest changes from the Github repository:

```
npm install codeforequity-at/botium-connector-dialogflow#master
```